# How to append time at a given line number in a given file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write time in every line in front of Text by check number of line in text file because I want to convert this text file to .srt file following this link.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111024/how-to-convert-a-txt-subtitle-file-to-srt-format

Every one line is 1 second.(start first line at 00:00:00:) My file has many line (500-1000 line up)
from

```
.......Text......... (first line)
.......Text......... (second line)
.......Text......... (third line)
    .
    .
    .
.......Text......... (60 line)
.......Text......... (61 line)
    .
    .
.................... (3600 line)
```

to this

```
00:00:01:.......Text......... (first line)
00:00:02:.......Text......... (second line)
00:00:03:.......Text......... (third line)
    .
    .
    .
00:01:00:.......Text......... (60 line)
00:01:01:.......Text......... (61 line)
    .
    .
01:00:00:.................... (3600 line)
```

I want to check the line number and write text in front of every line,
but there's a logical error in my code to check line number and open file write text at that line.
I don't know how to write for loop and compare number of line. I'm noob for this.

```
def numberline(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
           for i, l in enumerate(f):
                  pass
    return i + 1
numberline("/home/pi/gtest.txt")) 

dataFile = open("/home/pi/gtest.txt", "w")
    for line in range(numberline("/home/pi/gtest.txt")):
dataFile.write("00:00:%02d:\n" % line)
    dataFile.close()
```

Comment: This sounds like a python programming question - as such it is better suited to [so]

Comment: Your numberline function looks like it's returning only the `last line number+1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming a.txt is a text file that contains many lines)

```
import datetime


def make_time(num_of_seconds):
    hours = 0 if num_of_seconds < 3600 else num_of_seconds / 3600
    minutes = 0 if num_of_seconds < 60 else (num_of_seconds - hours * 3600) / 60
    seconds = num_of_seconds - (minutes * 60) - (hours * 3600)
    t = datetime.time(hours,minutes,seconds)
    return t.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


new_lines = []
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    lines = f_in.readlines()
for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    new_lines.append('{}:{}'.format(make_time(idx), line))
for l in new_lines:
    print(l.strip())
```